# Is drawable a singleton

Tags: android, colors, background-image, android-drawable

Got a behavior not sure if it is as it should be. 
If the drawable used in the view's background IS one instance shared with other views, how to change the individual's color?

having R.drawable.circle_shape as:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <solid android:color="#cccccc"/>
</shape>
```

used as two instances in one fragment

```
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/circle_1”
      android:layout_width="22dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
      android:shadowRadius="10.0"
                        />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/circle_2”
      android:layout_width="22dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
      android:shadowRadius="10.0"
                        />
```

the other use is for the list item’s template in other fragment

```
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/listItem_image”
      android:layout_width="22dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
      android:shadowRadius="10.0"
                        />
```

when I change the circle color for the instance c1, I noticed that c2 and listItem_image changes color too.

```
View c1 = (View) findViewById(R.id. circle_1);                                
c1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_shape);  // with or without this it will still affect the other ImageView which also uses R.drawable.circle_shape as background

((GradientDrawable) c1.getBackground()).setColor(intColor);
((GradientDrawable) c1.getBackground()).setStroke(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a singleton, but your guess is in the right direction. When you get a drawable, it shares state with other drawables. That's why when you modify one of them, you modify all the drawables which share state with it.

What you need to do is [mutate drawable](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html) so that a new state is created. In your case it will look something like this:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = ((GradientDrawable) c1.getBackground()).mutate();
drawable.setColor(intColor);
drawable.setStroke(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

The first line creates a new state, which allows the next two lines to change only the state of this particular drawable.